# In relativity can a single frame encompass two relatively stationary points such as Earth and Proxima Centauri 4 light years away?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I can understand you can't determine who's moving between a ship passing Earth at a constant relative velocity of $0.8c$ on to Proxima Centauri because of reciprocity of time and distance perspectives. But let's say you define the Earth frame as one also including Proxima Centauri.

The ship marks his time as zero on his watch the moment he co-locates with earth at speed. He does the same when he co-locates with Proxima at speed and sees his watch is at 3 years. He knows he was at a constant relative velocity of $0.8c$ because he is receiving televised signals where the picture moves in $1/3$ slow motion because of the Doppler shift ratio. Basically it's like a relativistic Doppler radar gun method.

His velocity is $x/t=0.8c$ but his gamma velocity is $\gamma v=x/t'= 4/3c$. His $\gamma v$ is relative to the Earth/Proxima frame and he only needs his watch and a star chart of distances from earth to determine his $\gamma v$. The guy on earth can also determine his $\gamma v$ relative to the Earth/Proxima frame as having moved nowhere relative to it so his $\gamma v=0$ while his $v$ relative to the ship remains $0.8c$.

This can be verified by light signals received years later but it isn't really necessary because the guy in the ship must know he was moving when he compares the $\gamma v$ he calculates from his watch and compares it to $v$ from his Doppler shift ratio.

So my question is, why can't relativity use this method to determine who was actually moving relative to the Earth/Proxima frame? This is not absolute motion or mixing up time perspectives. All I've done is redefined the earth frame to include Proxima Centauri so the spacetime path includes both start and end points.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to say who's moving relative to a given frame.  In your setup,   earth and PC are stationary and the traveler is moving.

Comment: Is Y meant to be gamma? Please use mathjax.

Comment: Yes Y is gamma. Is mathjax part of a full editor here or is it external?

Answer (score 1):

So on the advice of Paul Young I am going to post the philosophical answer to my question. If I had the time I'd verify it using math and graphically show it on spacetime diagrams (STD's). I can outline how the math proof would proceed:

I would draw 3 STD's. The first would have earth as a point frame which would be the vertical y-axis (stationary) and the ship would be a point frame represented as a velocity line of 5/4 slope. I would show how symmetry is preserved whether you draw it this way or have the ship stationary and the earth represented as a velocity line of -5/4 slope. Symmetry would be preserved between the two depictions whether for reciprocal time dilation, Doppler shift ratio, relativity of simultaneity or gamma velocity (Yv) between the earth and ship.

The second would be the extended earth frame that includes proxima centauri and a ship that is 4 light years long. This would be the classic pole in the barn or train in the platform STD. Symmetry would also be preserved here.

The third would cut the ship back down to a point. This would show the ends of the earth/proxima frame would not be relatively simultaneous from the ship's perspective because they are separated. So although I was saying the ship does not have to sync it's clock to earth's clock when it co-locates with earth or with proxima, I'm introducing an unsync'd relativity of simultaneity to the ship's clock. Hence I can say the ship has travelled 4 ly in 3 of its years but I have no valid comparison to how earth's or proxima's clocks are relative to the ship's clock so I can't make a valid determination that symmetry's broken. I should be able to mathematically show that the symmetry is restored once I take into account the relativity of simultaneity between the ship and earth's clock and the ship and proxima's clock which will not have the same clock reading from the ship's perspective.

So the answer to my question is that even though frames can consist of multiple relatively stationary points, you can't easily compare frames of different sizes unless you take into account how the separation between the points affects relativity of simultaneity.

Be wary, this answer looks like it makes sense but without doing the math to back it up, it's just philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

You can define any frame you want as stationary and then everything not at rest in that frame is moving.

What you *may* be thinking of is as follows:  define a frame such that the center of mass of all the stars and galaxies you can see is at rest, and then define anything not at rest with respect to that frame as "moving".  Such a frame is sometimes called "the frame of the Hubble flow".  It is a particularly interesting frame, but the laws of physics are not believed to be special for this frame.

Comment: Ok, let's consider the earth sets its stopwatch to zero when the ship passes and waits for word when the ship reaches PC to click the end of the time duration. The problem is the earth will have to wait 5 yrs its time for the ship to reach PC plus another 4 yrs for the light to travel from PC telling the earth to click its stopwatch. Only if the ship was 4 ly long would the earth's stopwatch record 3 yrs for the earth's trip from the front of the ship to its rear. But this didn't happen so only the ship can determine it crossed 4 ly in its time of 3 yrs.

Comment: let's say the ship was 4 light-years long (as reckoned by those on earth) and traveling at 4/5 c.  In this case the earth would see the back of the ship after five years - though people on the earth would not have any guarantee about what was going on at the front ...  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/barn_pole.html   see this famous example and think about the front and the back doors of the barn as PC and the earth ....

Comment: I've already said this here. My question specifically addresses the difference between a large frame and a small frame and mentions how it differs from the symmetry between 2 small frames and 2 large frames. I am looking for an answer where I'm misinterpreting the imbalance in symmetry between a large frame and one that travels within it. Time dilation and doppler shift ratio remain reciprocal but not Yv between the earth and the ship relative to the Earth/PC frame. Yv is reciprocal between 2 equal size frames. So what am I missing?

Comment: I think what you are missing is the Lorentz contraction.  People on earth consider PC to be 4 light years away.  But on the spaceship, travelling at 0.8c, the distance from earth to PC is only 4 / (5/3) = 12/5 light years.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No that's already included in Yv and it's covered by the ship's co-location at the start and end of the spacetime segment within the earth/PC frame. You only need to consider "length contraction"  if you use v instead of Yv. Length contraction is a figment of relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you other than "the spaceship is moving relative to the earth/PC frame".  That is the answer to the question you seem to have asked.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that didn't agree with mine and somehow convincingly showed how symmetry wasn't broken. The typical knee-jerk response is symmetry can't be broken no matter what my argument was. An asymmetry id frame size should not conclude in a time asymmetry based on perspective of the relative motion. It shouldn't.

Comment: And, indeed - I just don't see any asymmetry here.  I thought I understood you question, but know I see I don't.  The ship is moving relative to the Earth/PC frame in all ways just as the Earth/PC frame is moving relative to the ship.

Comment: I now see the asymmetry comes from the relativity of simultaneity. Earth and PC in a frame are still separated by distance so although their clocks are sync'd, to an outside ship they are not sync'd. When you consider the effects of relativity of simultaneity, symmetry is restored.

Comment: cool - you should consider writing an answer to your question so that somebody with the same issue as you had can go on to read it

Answer (score 0):

Your phrasing gives the impression that you have misunderstood the principle of relativity. It's not that, given two spaceships in the middle of space, you can't determine which one qualifies as being "at rest" because there are no reference points. Rather, the problem with labeling one of them as being "at rest" is that there isn't a privileged reference frame. That is, there is nothing in special relativity that says that, given a reference frame, it is not possible to determine what objects are at rest with respect to that reference frame. Rather, relativity says that there is no basis to single out a particular reference frame. There isn't a problem saying "This spaceship is at rest with respect to earth", the issue is that there is nothing special about being at rest with respect to earth; at object that is with at rest with respect to the earth isn't any more "at rest" than an object at rest with respect to another reference frame.

Comment: In relative velocity if you can arbitrarily set either as moving then you can't definitively establish either as moving. I'm saying this is true for the ship vs Earth frame but not in the ship vs Earth/Proxima frame. (There is no reference to an external frame.) Either frame can be set as stationary or moving but the symmetry is broken in the 2nd scenario. The moving ship's watch will not immediately match the moving Earth/Proxima's watch when you switch who's moving and who's stationary.

Comment: In essence, I have basically controlled the symmetry or lack thereof by choosing the earth frame to include or not include proxima centauri. Relativity must have symmetry whichever frame you choose stationary or moving so there must be some sort of rule that precludes me including PC into the earth frame.

Comment: re "precludes me including PC in the earth frame":  A frame is a set of vectors and PC is not a vector, so of course it is not included in any frame.  What are you actually trying to say?

Comment: A frame has a length. Take a look at Einstein's train.

Comment: A frame is composed of any number of participants that all have 0 velocity relative to each other.

Comment: @ralfcis :  "A frame has a length" --- what you mean, I guess, is that the **components** of a frame have lengths.  But in this context, the word "frame" is generally taken to mean "**orthonormal** frame", so all of the lengths have absolute value 1.

Comment: I'm talking about a frames in relativity where all objects within a frame are relatively stationary and where frames move at velocities relative to each other. I'm not talking about an orthonormal frame.

Comment: @ralfcis I'm starting to get the feeling that your understanding of relativity is too poor to have a meaningful discussion and explanation for how your understanding is mistaken. The reason you can't objectively say that one is moving is because "is moving" **does not refer to anything**. You might as well ask "Which frame is bafloogle?" The issue is not that either is equally bafloogle, the issue is not that one has to break the symmetry to single out one as bafloogle, the issue is that "bafloogle" isn't a real word, and "at rest" is not a real term in relativity.

Comment: And there is no symmetry that is broken when including PC, either, which suggests that "symmetry" is another concept that you don't understand.

Comment: I clearly and carefully spelled out the scenario of what is moving relative to what. Bafoogle was not one of the participants. A spacetime path must begin and end with co-location of frames. My question is, "but what if I make one frame large enough to include the entire spacetime path,The ship would co-locate with the start and end within that frame but the earth/PC frame would not co-locate with the ship's spacetime path start and end." Would that not be symmetry broken?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing two related concepts, namely time dilation and the relativity of simultaneity. You appear to consider that in the case in which only the rocket and Earth appear, the clock of each will be seen as running slow in the frame of the other, but then you imagine that if clocks on PC are taken into account the arrangement is no longer symmetrical. You are simply misleading yourself.

Part of your difficulty is that you do not use the word 'frame' in its usual sense. In SR, you should consider all frames to be boundless.

To see the symmetry in the SR effects, you need simply imagine a second clock stationary in the frame of the rocket and positioned so that in that frame it is floating past PC at the same time as the rocket is passing Earth. You should now see that the rocket moving between clocks on Earth and PC is exactly symmetrical with PC moving between the floating clock and the rocket.

Finally, the clocks are merely devices to help us visualise the effects. You don't need them mathematically- you can simply define points and intervals in spacetime in an abstract way symbolically.